# How to write the following mongo lookup query in Yii2

Tags: mongodb, yii2

I am using this [mongo extension](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-mongodb) in Yii2.

I have 2 collections named `ServiceProvider` and `Parents`. In `ServiceProvider` there is subdocument `(PostCommentIDs)` containing IDs of parents.

Another collection `Parents` contains all parent information.

I wanted to join the 2 collection. I have achieved it through the following mongo query.

But using the above extension how do I write this query in Yii2.

```
db.ServiceProvider.aggregate([
   {
      $unwind: "$PostCommentIDs"
   },
   {
      $lookup:
         {
            from: "Parents",
            localField: "PostCommentIDs",
            foreignField: "ID",
            as: "ParentDetails"
        }
   },
   {
      $match: { "ParentDetails": { $ne: [] } }
   }
])
```

Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution. It may help someone.

```
$collection = Yii::$app->mongodb->getCollection('ServiceProvider');
$result = $collection->aggregate([
            ['$unwind' => '$PostCommentUserIDs'],
            [ 
                '$lookup' => 
                    [
                        'from' => 'Parents',
                        'localField' => 'PostCommentUserIDs',
                        'foreignField' => 'ID',
                        'as' => 'ParentDetails'
                    ] 
            ],
            [
                '$match' => [
                    'ParentDetails' => [ '$ne' => []  ]
                ]
            ]
]);
```

Comment: I am getting 'pipeline' option must be specified as an array error

Answer (score 1):

Use this way in current explanation: Pipeline must be in an array always

```
$collection = Yii::$app->mongodb->getCollection('ServiceProvider');
$result = $collection->aggregate([
        ['$unwind' => '$PostCommentUserIDs'],
        [ 
            '$lookup' => 
                [
                    'from' => 'Parents',
                    'localField' => 'PostCommentUserIDs',
                    'foreignField' => 'ID',
                    'as' => 'ParentDetails'
                ] 
        ],
        [
            '$match' => [
                'ParentDetails' => [ '$ne' => []  ]
            ]
        ]
      ]);
```