# Yii2. How to use lookup in MongoDB/ActiveQuery?

Tags: mongodb, gridview, yii2

I am creating a GridView. The widget uses ActiveQuery to search. According to its [documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activequery), it was originally created to work with MySQL. Because of this, the native code allows one to add a relational search with [joinWith()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activequery#joinWith()-detail)

My database is mongodb, and I would like to search a relation. The only way to join in mongodb is use [lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) (aggregation). When I try to add aggregation to ActiveQuery, I get the error:

> Calling unknown method: yii\mongodb\ActiveQuery::aggregate()

How do I implement a [Yii2 aggregation lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36951391/how-to-write-the-following-mongo-lookup-query-in-yii2) to ActiveQuery, so as to be able to join a second collection for the GridView search?

Comment: you should add your relevant code too.

Answer (score 0):

I used previously and don't have problem in this solution. Check the Yii2 version and MongoDB version.

help full link :
[Guide to usage aggregation in Yii2](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-mongodb/blob/master/docs/guide/usage-aggregation.md)

Comment: I ended up just merging the two collections, then using scenarios for two (or more) separate CRUD's to write to it then just querying bits of the collection at a time. I just wish there was aggregation in ActiveQuery just there's joinWith.